# Nginx Error: unknown directive "uwsgi_param"

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm trying to install deploy my flask service on nginx with u-wsgi module.
I'm getting this error when I restart nginx--

```
`Restarting nginx: nginx.
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "uwsgi_param" in /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`
```

my flask config file is --

```
server{
    listen  2000;
    server_name _;
#location = /flaskapplication { rewrite ^ /flaskapplication/; }
#include uwsgi_params;
location /flaskapplication { try_files $uri @flaskapplication; }
location @flaskapplication {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /home/uday/demo/flask_performance;
  uwsgi_modifier1 30;
  uwsgi_pass unix:/home/uday/demo/uwsgi.sock;
}
}
```

I tried to search for the problem and found that installing `nginx-full` may solve the problem.
When I tried `apt-get install nginx-full` error is--

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx-full : Depends: passenger-common (>= 1:3.0.17) but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: passenger-common (< 1:3.0.18) but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
enter code here
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to install Uwsgi.

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo apt-get install uwsgi
sudo apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python
sudo apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-http
```

To install packages with dependencies, specify the -f flag.

```
sudo apt-get -f install nginx-full
```

Comment: thanks for reply but I'm facing broken package issue with nginx-full

Comment: pls refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928407/how-to-install-nginx-full