# How to install nginx-full

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, passenger, uwsgi

I'm trying to install nginx-full on my 12.04 machine(upgraded from 11.04)
getting this error with apt-get--

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nginx-full : Depends: passenger-common (>= 1:3.0.17) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: passenger-common (< 1:3.0.18) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

with aptitude getting this

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nginx-light : Conflicts: nginx-full but 1:1.2.3-1~38~natty1 is to be installed.
nginx-full : Conflicts: nginx-light but 1:1.2.3-1~38~natty1 is installed.
passenger-common : Depends: libev3 (>= 3.0) which is a virtual package.
  Depends: ruby-rack but it is not going to be installed.
  Depends: passenger-common1.8 (= 1:3.0.17+120~natty1) but it is not going to be installed. or
         passenger-common1.9.1 (= 1:3.0.17+120~natty1) but it is not going to be installed.
```

When I try to install `passenger-common` it depends on `libev3` which is not available.
How can I solve this problem.
Output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` this is empty.

Comment: You have some mess in your repositories. Default nginx-full does not depends on passenger

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a messed up package database. First uninstall all packages that begin with nginx and passenger, then try again.